# effects of different scenarios on a single cycle datapath (beq command)

Tags: mips, computer-science, cpu-architecture

I am stuck and unsure regarding the following situation.

I have the following datacycle:

[image: given datacycle]

and I know that in 0x3000 I have the following command: `beq $t1,$t2,home` - where `home` is 0x30AC, $t1=$t2=0x2000.

For some reason, I cannot translate it into hexa using online converters. The command I tried is: `beq 0x2000, 0x2000, 0x30AC`. Since the syntax of a beq command, as far as I know is: `BEQ rs, rt, offset [I-type]`, then I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Anyways, my main problem are with the following cases:

1. If the control line of ALUSrc is stuck on 1, what will the command do?
2. If MemWrite is stuck on 1, what will the command do?
3. If ALUOp is stuck on the value 10 (binary), what will the command do?

What I think:

1. If alusrc equals one, then the lower 16 bits will be taken (with sign extenstion) from the command and added to $rs (0x2000).
2. If Memwrite equals one, then the data memory will be written unexpectedly.
3. I really don't know what will happen if ALUop will be stuck on 10. would really appreciate explanations regarding this situation.

I tried to elaborate as much as I can to make it understandable and also provide my attempts and insights (if correct, hope that some are lol).

Comment: those are called *instructions*, not commands

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation. could you help me with the question please?